# I can't get ListItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone in the StackOverflow community, I wanna try to have a sidebar like amazon but I fail to have the same. As I see all data of my code is working very well I try it all with `console.log()` function. But the inverse happens when I try to use it in the component function it doesn't work as I want. It doesn't display the subcategories list under every header category.

It returns this error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). 
    at CategoriesBar.js:69:1
```

So the `categories[category]` are undefined for the code. Sorry for my bad English

this is my code :

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import ListSubheader from "@mui/material/ListSubheader";
import axios from "axios";

function CategoriesBar() {
  let [categories, setCategories] = useState({});
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      axios.get("/api/categories").then((res) => {
        const categoriesData = res.data.map((cat) => cat.name);

        let newSub = {};
        const catg = res.data;
        catg.forEach((category, i) => {
          let categoryId = category.id;
          if (catg) {
            setData(categoriesData);
          }
          axios.get(`/api/subcategories/${categoryId}`).then((res) => {
            const subcategories = res.data.subcategories;
            const subName = subcategories.map((sub) => sub.name);

            newSub[category.name] = subName;
          });

          setCategories(newSub);
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);
  console.log(categories);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-white font-bold bg-green-700 pt-2.5 pl-2 pb-2.5 pr-8 w-96 text-2xl">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          strokeWidth={1.5}
          stroke="currentColor"
          className="w-10 inline-block pr-2 "
        >
          <path
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M17.982 18.725A7.488 7.488 0 0012 15.75a7.488 7.488 0 00-5.982 2.975m11.963 0a9 9 0 10-11.963 0m11.963 0A8.966 8.966 0 0112 21a8.966 8.966 0 01-5.982-2.275M15 9.75a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"
          />
        </svg>
        Hello, Sign In
      </div>
      <List
        sx={{
          width: "100%",
          maxWidth: 384,
          bgColor: "background.paper",
          position: "absolute",
          overflowY: "scroll",
          height: "100%",
          "& ul": { padding: 0 },
        }}
        subheader={<li />}
      >
        {data.map((category, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <ul>
              <ListSubheader>{category}</ListSubheader>
              {categories[category].map((item, index) => (
                <ListItem key={item}>
                  <ListItemText primary={item} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </li>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CategoriesBar;
```

Comment: You're trying to call `.map()` on `categories[category]`, which is empty. This is happening because you are trying to render the subcategories before they have been added to the "categories" object.

Comment: So how to fix it my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it causes because of timing issue

you need to await for subcategories to come and then setCategory state with newSub

like this :

```
  catg.forEach(async (category, i) => {
          let categoryId = category.id;
          if (catg) {
            setData(categoriesData);
          }
          await axios.get(`/api/subcategories/${categoryId}`).then(res => {
            const subcategories = res.data.subcategories;
            const subName = subcategories.map(sub => sub.name);

            newSub[category.name] = subName;
          });

          setCategories(newSub);
        });
```

Comment: good, thank you my friend, but it return just for the subcategories of the first category.then when i reloading the page it return the subcategories of the the second category.

Comment: it work very well i eliminate the .then from the second axios.get() request,and i make "const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/subcategories/${categoryId}`);.thank you a lot my friend.i appreciate your help.

Comment: but the problem is when i reload the page all the subcategories become hidden.